Quasi isomorphic left-bounded and right-bounded complexes of projectives
Let $(A, \mathfrak{m}, k)$ be a complete Noetherian local commutative ring and suppose $\varphi : P_{\bullet} \to Q_{\bullet}$ is a quasi-isomorphism between complexes of finite free $A$-modules such that $P_n = 0$ for $n \ll 0$ and $Q_n = 0$ for $n \gg 0$. Does it follow that $P_\bullet, Q_\bullet$ are quasi isomorphic to perfect complexes?
Equivalently, if $Q_{\bullet}$ is a complex of finite free modules such that $Q_n = 0$ for $n \gg 0$ and $H_n(Q) = 0$ for $n \ll 0$ is $Q$ quasi-isomorphic to a perfect complex?
Edit: See the paper Acyclic complexes of injectives and finitistic dimensions for related results

I think you're missing an assumption: should $\varphi$ be a quasi-isomorphism?

Yes, sorry about that!

I presume from the subscript notation you've used that you mean chain complexes rather than cochain complexes: i.e., $P_\bullet$ is bounded to the right and $Q_\bullet$ is bounded to the left? Actually, I think you must do, as otherwise I don't think the "Equivalently" statement would be equivalent.

Assuming that $P_\bullet$ and $Q_\bullet$ are chain (rather than cochain) complexes, this doen't follow.
Let $k$ be a field and $A=k[x]/(x^2)$, let
$$P_\bullet = \cdots\xrightarrow{x}A\xrightarrow{x}A\rightarrow0\rightarrow\cdots$$
be a projective resolution of $A/(x)$, with the last nonzero term in degree zero, and let
$$Q_\bullet = \cdots\rightarrow 0\rightarrow A\xrightarrow{x}A\xrightarrow{x}\cdots$$
be an injective resolution of $A/(x)$, with the first nonzero term in degree zero. Since $A$ is self-injective, the terms of $Q_\bullet$ are also projective.
Then $P_\bullet$ and $Q_\bullet$ are not perfect, since $A/(x)$ has infinite projective and injective dimension, but there is a quasi-isomorphism from $P_\bullet$ to $Q_\bullet$.
